# Streamlining Compiling with batch files..?

Tags: batch-file

Here's the situation:

I'm developing various projects that have the same compile procedure/file structure. I'd like to, instead of typing `javac dir\*.class` I'd like to just use a batch file "compile.bat"

The file structure is typically com\jseb{project name}.java files however I'd like to be as abstract as possible to allow for the use of multiple packages in the future. Here's what I have so far (does not work):

```
@echo off
javac com\*\*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a generic batch file that takes in a directory name.

compile.bat:

```
@echo off
javac com\%1\*.java
```

The `%1` means to substitute the first parameter passed into the batch file.

To use from the command line:

```
compile proj-dir
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile all projects, then

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad com\*') do javac "com\%%i\*.java"
```

to build all projects serially (one at a time)

or

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad com\*'
 ) do start "Compiling %%i" javac "com\%%i\*.java"
```

to build all in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Move to better software engineering methods and techniques and to more sophisticated, robust and productive software development tools.

1. Learn and use a build system. Begin with **Ant** and then move to **Maven**.
2. and learn and use an IDE. Try **Eclipse**.

With very little effort, beginning with the provided sample ant scripts, you can achieve such a solution to automatically compile, with dependency checking, all the code files in a complex directory structure.

Comment: Really it comes down to having a (possibly undeserved) hatred for Eclipse. I enjoy using Sublime Text and the command line - I realize that it's not the prettiest or easiest or smartest route but it's how I do it.

Comment: in that case, just give a try to **ant**. I firmly recommend.